# Bootstrap - Not all nav dropdown content is showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I'm having a really rough time trying to get my dropdown navigation to work - not all the content is showing up when the "caret" is clicked. I think it may be an issue with the z-index, but I can't get that to work either. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="jumbotron"><a href="index.html">Gaming Nation</a></h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="myNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <ul id="nav-ul" class="nav navbar list-inline">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Reviews<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Adventure</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Fighting</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Platforms</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">RPG</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Shooter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Strategy</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Survival</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this site...">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "goodTimes";
    src: url("../fonts/goodtimes.ttf");
}

body {
    background-color: #fde6e7;
}

.list-inline {
    display: flex;
}

.list-inline li {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

nav {
    z-index: 111;
}

nav h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-family: goodTimes;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav a {
    color: #1047C6;
}

nav li {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-color: #ededed;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    border: 4px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't show? It seems to work fine for me https://www.bootply.com/dYuBt0ZuEO

Comment: @j08691 You're right. The content loaded up fine for a larger screen, which made me realize that I was only having problems with the mobile viewport (xs breakpoint). I found a workaround - giving the ".collapse.in" selector a property value of "overflow: visible". This made the mobile breakpoint work as well. Thank you for helping me see that the issue involved just the mobile breakpoint.